# NxN matrix using embedded for loops

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, matrix

I am trying to create an NxN matrix using embedded for loops. I think I almost have it but I feel like I am missing something in the loops. The user is suppose to give me n and I generate the matrix based of that input.

```
public static void printMatrix( int n ){



    for ( int i = 1; i < n; i++ ){
        System.out.println(" "+(int)(Math.random() + 0.5));

        for( int k = 1; k < n+1; k++)
            System.out.print(" "+(int)(Math.random() + 0.5));

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried running this? What do you feel is missing?

Comment: Yes, you're missing a lot.  I see no matrix here, just two loops.

Answer (score 2):

You only need the print statement within the second loop to print a "matrix". i.e.,

```
public static void printMatrix(int n)
{
    for( int i = 1; i <= n; i++ )
    {
        for( int k = 1; k <= n; k++ )
            System.out.print("\t"+(int)(Math.random() + 0.5));
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Actually, here you aren't really creating a matrix (meaning you aren't storing it in any structure, say a 2D array), but are only printing out `n*n` number of random values.

To do so as well,

```
public static void printMatrix(int n)
{
    int[][] yourArray = new int[n][n];
    for( int i = 1; i <= n; i++ )
        for( int k = 1; k <= n; k++ )
            yourArray[i][k] = Math.random() + 0.5; //Populating the array.
    for( int i = 1; i <= n; i++ )
    {
        for( int k = 1; k <= n; k++ )
            System.out.print("\t"+yourArray[i][k]); //Reading data from the array.
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are trying to use first `for` loop to control number of rows in matrix. This is good idea but take a look at your first for loop

```
for ( int i = 1; i < n; i++)
```

How many iterations will be there?

Now it seems that you are trying to print all elements of one row using second `for` loop, which is also good idea. The only problem is that you are printing additional random number with new line mark before you print elements of row inside this second `for`. Remember that you are already printing all elements of that row inside second for so you don't need to print another one before it.

Also try printing new line mark after you print entire row if you don't want to end with empty line at start.